# Remove folders from php scandir listing

Tags: php

I have a php script `$filelist = scandir('myfolder/')` which list outs files from my folder. But it is adding child folders also to the array so that they are also populated when i print the result using `foreach`. I want to remove folders from getting added to the array. How can I do this??

Comment: Do you want to remove *all* child elements, listing only the top-level folders in 'myfolder/'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the function [glob()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php), and check if the item of array [is_dir()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php).

Answer (score 11):

Simple way

```
$dir = 'myfolder/';
$filelist = scandir($dir);
foreach ($filelist as $key => $link) {
    if(is_dir($dir.$link)){
        unset($filelist[$key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I add this line for array reorder and get a array with new index 0,

`$filelist = array_values($filelist);`

Answer (score 7):

A **clean concise solution** could be to use **[array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)** to exclude all sub-directories like this

```
$files = array_filter(scandir('directory'), function($item) {
    return !is_dir('directory/' . $item);
});
```

This effectively also removes the `.` and `..` which represent the current and the parent directory respectively.

Comment: It worked for me but i needed to use a global variable so I added the use() part, just in case somebody else needs:
`$picturesArr = array_filter($files, function($item) use ($dir) {
    return !is_dir($dir.'/'.$item);
});`

Comment: Also don't forget to rum this through array_values() else you might find undefined offsets!

Answer (score 4):

If you know what the name of the folders are, you could create an array of these folders and then use array_diff to remove them from the result:

```
$folders = array('..', '.', 'folder');
$files = array_diff(scandir($dir), $folders);
```

Answer (score 1):

scandir returns an array of folders. You can remove any element of the array like this:

```
unset( $filelist[0] );
```

where 0 is the index of the element you wish to remove. You can also use array_search() if you need to find directories by name.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<?php
$dir = "/example";

$filelist = new Array();
if (is_dir($dir)) {
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
            if (!is_dir($file)) {
                $filelist[] = $file;
            }
        }
        closedir($dh);
    }
}
?>
```

It's like doing a scandir, but checking the type of the returned files